# How to give a direct link to one of my JQuery Tabs?

Tags: jquery

**My Page:** https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/InteractiveMap/implementing.html

I would like to know, if it is possible to give a direct link to one of my tabs on my page. For example, if you click on the Canada image, it will load content for that image of which will be used for later usage and whatnot. Is it possible to enter a URL to directly do that?

Alike the way you can go onto Google Maps, look around and then get a direct link for what your now looking at?

**Example:**

https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/InteractiveMap/implementing.html#Current

Will take you to the Current tab of the side menu, it does not currently, but this is something I would like to be able to do.

Best Regards,
Tim

**Edit:**

Tab switcher inside another: http://jsfiddle.net/3N4n2/

The JQuery:

```
$('#tab-wrapper li:first').addClass('active');
$('#maps-slider li:first').addClass('active');
$('#tab-body > div').hide();
$('#Current > div').hide();
$('#tab-body > div:first').show();
$('#Current > div:first').show();

$('#tab-wrapper a').click(function() {
    $('#tab-wrapper li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var activeTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#tab-body > div:visible').hide();
    $(activeTab).show();
    return false;
});

$('#maps-slider a').click(function() {
    $('#maps-slider li').removeClass('active');
    $('#tab-wrapper li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $('#tab-wrapper #Current-Tab').addClass('active');
    var activeTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#Current > div:visible').hide();
    $('#tab-body > div:visible').hide();
    $('#Current > div:first').hide();
    $(activeTab).show();
    $('#tab-body > #Current').show();
    return false;
});
```

### Update:

I have updated my live version, of which I have it working now. The code used is the following:

```
// Parse URL Queries Method
(function($){
    $.getQuery = function( query ) {
        query = query.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
        var expr = "[\\?&]"+query+"=([^&#]*)";
        var regex = new RegExp( expr );
        var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
        if( results !== null ) {
            return results[1];
            return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

// Document load
$(function(){
    var test_query = $.getQuery('test');
    alert(test_query); // For the URL http://YOUR DOMAIN/index.html?test=yes, the value would be "yes"
});
```

Comment: The Google link contains all the parameters to recreate the state of that view. You need to somehow keep or recreate the state of your app.

Comment: @David could you please give an incline to what I would search for to find out more information on how to do this please?

Comment: The url my have multiple parameters server.com/myapp?selectedMap=a&selectedTab=2&viewMode=collapsed - or - take an id and get that state from a server, e.g. database.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code please and a jsFiddle in addition? Once your site is dead, link-rot sets in or similar this question is of no use without the relevant code to any future user possibly looking for a solution to a similar issue.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I'll create something for future users to be able to gain help from this question to, I'll add some code, a working version of what I am doing, however I just cannot see a thing like this working in JSFiddle but be sure I will add something. Also, at this moment in time, I need to go, but once I am back, I'll make a tab switch and implement this and add a jsfiddle, that is once I know how to myself.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a variable to the url and parse it.
Example link:  https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/InteractiveMap/implementing.html?tab=1

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    // parse URL for variables
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    // return an object with keys of names of the variables and associated values 
    // The returned object with the example URL is equivalent to vars = {tab:1};
    return vars;
}
// assign individual variables to the key values
var myTAB = getUrlVars()["tab"];
// just set the active variable in your jquery tab declaration = myTAB or update my generic selector to your own to set it afterwards...
if(myTAB) { $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active", myTAB); }
```

Comment: Is this JQuery or plain Javascript? Regardless, I have added it to my script on my page, I presume it is my own error to as why it is not working and breaks all my JQuery? Also, could you please add some comments to as what things do so I can work with this? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: I've added a fiddle and some code for others to see. I've woken up with an extreme headache and cannot think right now, but I'll try and implement your code as soon as I can.

Comment: I've been slowly looking at your code and tried implementing the first section adding "alert(vars);" however no alert happens. I have updated the live version.

Comment: If you want to 'see' the object I would suggest using `alert(JSON.stringify(vars));`, but since `vars` is defined within the function you would have to put the alert within the function or change `vars` to `getUrlVars()`...